# Plesk configuration stuck after installation

Tags: plesk, plesk-onyx

I installed plesk following this:

https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/deployment-guide/plesk-installation-and-upgrade-on-single-server/installing-plesk-using-installer-gui/installing-plesk-for-linux-using-installer-gui.76446/

And all went well, no errors or anything. I can provide any logs if needed. I'm now on:

https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/deployment-guide/plesk-installation-and-upgrade-on-single-server/plesk-single-server-postinstall-configuration.76454/

On the part for Plesk Onyx 17.8

What I do after I access the https://ip:8443 and enter the ROOT user and server root pw:

- I leave the contact name as Administrator
- I give my own personal working email
- I generate a password which i copy into a file for later
- I click the trial license option
- Confirm the terms
- Enter Plesk

What happens afterwards is I get a screen with a green bar on the bottom and it says "initializing plesk". After that, by the guide, I should be on a different page, but it just takes me back to the same page where I must type name email and so on.

I have also tried logging in with Administrator and the new password rather than root, but it says invalid credentials. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Any workaround found? Ive the same problem !